# How can I get a string(Mix of digit and char) up to last digit using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have strings like:

" 5473 & 4835 how to find the index"

" 5473 how to find the index"

" 5473 & A-121-2 how to find the index"

" A-121-2 how to find the index"

How can I extract the string up to last digit using regex.

For example, the result I want in above is like this:

" 5473 & 4835"

" 5473"

" 5473 & A-121-2"

" A-121-2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use greediness of `*`

```
^.*\d
```

1. `^` asserts that we are at the start of a line.
2. `.*` will greedily  matches all the characters upto the last
3. `\d` and then it backtracks  in-order to find a digit character.

**Example:**

```
>>> re.search(r'^.*\d', " 5473 & 4835 how to find the index").group()
' 5473 & 4835'
>>> re.search(r'^.*\d', 'A-121-2 how to find the index').group()
'A-121-2'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sY4uC9/5)

Comment: Can you please tell how does this work? I am trying to learn regex

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. One more question: What if I have something like "No.- 12345 asbf"  and I only need to get the result as "12345".

Comment: `re.findall(r'\d+', string)` .